# pulse width using interruption flag

Tags: c, microcontroller, interrupt, pic, pulse

I would like to measure a pulse width using pic 18f4550 CCP in capture mode.
The idea is:
when the CCP model receives a rising edge, the timer1 starts, and after each interruption of the Timer 1, x which is a constant with an initial value of 0 increases by 1, when the CCP model receives a falling edge timer1 stops and the increase of x must also stop so that its value can be used in the calculation of the pulse.
the problem i found is that the increasing of x doesn't stop and the code works like a counter
and as i am a newbie in pic programming I couldn't find the error.
if anyone can help i will be grateful.
the code I am using is bellow.
thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "osc_config.h"
#include "LCD_8bit_file.h"
#include <string.h>

int x=0;

void main()
{
    unsigned long comtage;
    unsigned long DEPHASAGE[20];
    float Deph_tempo;
    
    TRISCbits.TRISC2=1;
    
    IRCF0=1;     
    IRCF1=1;
    IRCF2=1;  
    
    LCD_Init();
    
    LCD_String_xy(0,0,"pulse"); 
 
    PIE1bits.CCP1IE=1;
    PIR1bits.CCP1IF=0; 
    
    CCP1CON=0b00000101; 
    CCPR1=0;        
    
    T1CONbits.RD16=0;
    T1CKPS0=0;
    T1CKPS1=0;
    TMR1CS=0;
    
    while(1)        
    {    
        CCP1CON         = 0b00000101;
        PIR1bits.CCP1IF = 0;
        TMR1ON          = 0; 
        TMR1            = 0;

        while (!PIR1bits.CCP1IF)
            ;

        TMR1ON          = 1; 
        CCP1CON         = 0b00000100;
        PIR1bits.CCP1IF = 0;
    
        if (TMR1IF==1)
        {
            x++;
            TMR1IF=0;
        }
    
        while (!PIR1bits.CCP1IF)
            ; 

        comtage = x; 
    
        Deph_tempo = ((float)comtage /7843.13 ); 
        sprintf(DEPHASAGE,"%.5f  ",Deph_tempo); 

        LCD_String_xy(2,0,DEPHASAGE);
    }
    x = 0;
}                              

``
```

Comment: I've fixed indentation a bit.  There is a reason why keeping code tidy is important.  You   The statemet `x = 0;` is outside of your never ending loop and thus unreachable.  You should move that statement inside the while loop.  Preferably toward the top of the loop , near the `TMR1 = 0;` statement, this would make the code easier to read and reason about.

Comment: thanks, I have already tested this choice but  my LCD displays a constant value even if I change the pulse width.

Comment: There are other bugs in this code... x is always 0, for example.  What are you trying to do?  What are your parameters?  I mean what range of the pulse witdths are you trying to read?  It's very difficult to give an answer without background.

Comment: I see that I have misrepresented my problem, so I apologize for not giving you the necessary information.
Like all newbies, I had a lot of bugs in this code. Now I would like to measure a pulse between 10uS and 1S.
The problem is, my code can't measure pulses above 0.03S without using interrupts, and when I use them I can't write the correct code.
Thank you

Comment: What is your oscillator speed?  And the required precision?  That also is important. For the maths.

Comment: I use an internal 8Mhz oscillator, for the precision I like to get as high as possible using an internal oscillator.

Comment: There is one way you can achieve what you want to do...  It's a bit tricky, since you need a timer that's more than 16 bits wide.  It is possible to use both TMR1 and TMR3 to work with CCPCON, and get a 19-bit wide timer, at Fosc = 8MHz, your clock input to the timers is 2MHz, which means this 24 bit timer will rollover after 2^19 * .5 us = 264 us seconds or so...  That's still a bit short.

Comment: To extend the range of your hardware counters, you can either divide your oscillator clock by 4, and run at 2MHz = 500 K instructions per second, or use TMR2 to generate a PWM you'll connect externally electrically to T13CKI/RC0 and use as a clock.  That's what I'd do.

Comment: The idea is to use TMR1 with no prescaler, and TMR3 with a 1:8 prescaler, use the CCP special event trigger (described in datasheet at section 12.5) to reset both timers simultaneously.  Then switch the CCP module to capture mode and wait for capture.  No interrupts needed.   I'll post an answer later today... I'm also busy elsewhere.

Comment: This would give you a 2us resulution and a max pulse with of 1.048 s.  Of course, the ideal solution would involve a MCU with a 32 bit timer, something like a PIC24.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one way you can achieve what you want to do...  It's a bit tricky, since you need a timer that's more than 16 bits wide.  It is possible to use both TMR1 and TMR3 to work with CCPCON, and get a 19-bit wide timer, at Fosc = 8MHz, your clock input to the timers is 2MHz, which means this 19 bit timer will rollover after 2^19 * .5 us = 264 us seconds or so...  We could use TMR3IF to detect a rollover and make it 20 bits, but that's still a bit short.

There is also the possibility of using TMR0, which has an 1:256 prescaler, but you'd need to feed TMR0 with an external clock.  You can use TMR3 and the PWM generator to generate a 500kHz clock signal on CCP2/RC1, and route that to TK0CKI/RA4.  This would effectively create a 26-bit counter, with a resolution of 4/Fosc = .5 us, and a range of 33.55 seconds.  You could increase resolution by using the PLL to increase oscillator frequency.  This also has the advantage that it would be quite precise.  Repeatability depends on the loops.  Using an ISR to catch the interrupts would improve repeatability quite a bit.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "osc_config.h"
#include "LCD_8bit_file.h"
#include <string.h>

void main()
{
    unsigned long count = 0;

    // Setting up TMR0 for extarnal clock on T0CKI/RA4

    LATAbits.LATA4    = 0;
    TRISAbits.TRISA0  = 1;     // RC0 as input
    T0CON             = 0x27   // Prescaler 1:256, 0->1 transition, T0CKI input 
    TMR0IE            = 0;     // mask interrupts.

    // Setting up TMR1/CCP1CON for capture on RC2/CCP1

    TRISCbits.TRISC2  = 1;     // CCP2/RC2 as input
    LATCbits.LATC2    = 0;
    T1CON             = 0x80   // internal clock oscillator off, 1:1 pre, 16 bits reads
    TMR1              = 0;
    CCP1CON           = 0x05   // set capture mode on rising edge
    CCP2IE            = 0;     // mask interrupts
    TMR1IE            = 0;

    // Setting up TMR2/CCP2CON for generating the clock on CCP2/RC1

    LATCbits.LATC1    = 0;     // clear RC1 latch
    TRISCbits.TRICSC1 = 0;     // RC1 as output
    T2CON             = 0;     // timer2 off, prescaler 1:1, post scaler 1:1
    PR2               = 3;     // PWM frequency = (Fosc / 4) / 4
    TMR2              = 0;
    CCPR2             = 0;
    CCP2CON           = 0x1C;  // CCP2M = PWM mode, DCB2<0> = 1 (LSB for duty cycle compare) 
    CCP2IE            = 0;     // mask interrupts
    TMR2IE            = 0;

    while (1)
    {
        // get ready to capture.
        TMR2ON          = 0;      // stop our timing clock.
        TMR0ON          = 0;      // this reset TMR0 prescaler
        TMR0            = 0;      // clear timers.
        TMR1            = 0;
        TMR2            = 0;
        TMR0ON          = 1;      // Timer 0 is ready to count.
        CCP1CON         = 0x05;   // set capture mode on rising edge
        PIR1bits.CCP1IF = 0;

        while (!PIR1bits.CCP1IF)  // wait for event
            ;

        PIR1bits.CCP1IF = 0;
        CCP1CON         = 0x04;   // set capture mode on falling edge

        TMR1ON          = 1;
        TMR2ON          = 1;

        while (!PIR1bits.CCP1IF)  // wait for event
            ;
        
        // here we have to make sure to keep the same latency as after 
        // rising edge, so we are precise. 
        PIR1bits.CCP1IF = 0;
        CCP1CON         = 0x04;   // set capture mode on rising edge

        TMR1ON          = 0;
        TMR2ON          = 0;      // also stops TMR0 

        // TMR0's clock is is divided by 2²2 * 2^8 = 2^10
        // its lower 6 bits should be equal to the upper 6 bits
        // of TMR1.   
        count = ((TMR0 & 0xFFC0 << 10) + TMR1;

        // convert to us
        count >>= 1;

        // display...
    }
}
```

That's as close as I can get without an actual device and a scope in front of me.  Let me know if you have any question or encounter any issues.

Comment: thanks, I will test this code and all the choices you have given. thanks again

Comment: There was a mistake in the calculation of `count`.  Sorry about that.

Comment: it's all about ideas, small mistakes can be corrected.